# enable dates based on condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on angularjs application.I have two date fields, requirement is when user selects date in Available Date calendar,the Expire Date field should enable and user should be able to choose the date with in 24days from the date selected in Available Date field.
Example, when user selects date in Available Date field as 2017-03-02, the expire Date field should enable and the calendar should only enable 24days followed by 2017-03-02 (i.e.,2017-03-25), and all dates should be disabled so that user cannot able to select any date after 2017-03-25 or before 2017-03-02..
Please find the demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cpu4euoj/139/)

js code:

```
myApp.controller("myController", ["$scope",
    function($scope) {
        var today = new Date();
        $scope.AvailableDate = new Date();
        $scope.ExpireDate = new Date();
        $scope.dateFormat = 'yyyy-MM-dd';
        $scope.availableDateOptions = {
            formatYear: 'yy',
            startingDay: 1,
            minDate: "2016-03-12",
            maxDate: today
        };
        $scope.expireDateOptions = {
            formatYear: 'yy',
            startingDay: 1,
            minDate: today,
            maxDate: "2017-06-12"
        };
        $scope.availableDatePopup = {
            opened: false
        };
        $scope.expireDatePopup = {
            opened: false
        };
        $scope.ChangeExpiryMinDate = function(availableDate) {
            if (availableDate != null) {
                var expiryMinDate = new Date(availableDate);
                $scope.expireDateOptions.minDate = expiryMinDate;
                $scope.ExpireDate = expiryMinDate;
                //code to set maxDates in Expire Date field -start
                 var date = new Date(expiryMinDate);
                 var newdate = new Date(date);
                 newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + 3);
                 var dd = newdate.getDate();
                 var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
                 var y = newdate.getFullYear();
                  var someFormattedDate = y + '/' + dd + '/' + mm;
                  $scope.expireDateOptions.maxDate = someFormattedDate;
                //code to set maxDates in Expire Date field -end
            }
        };
        $scope.ChangeExpiryMinDate();
        $scope.OpenAvailableDate = function() {
            $scope.availableDatePopup.opened = !$scope.availableDatePopup.opened;
        };
        $scope.OpenExpireDate = function() {
            $scope.expireDatePopup.opened = !$scope.expireDatePopup.opened;
        };
    }
]);
```

Below is the code i tried but not succeded.

```
 var date = new Date(expiryMinDate);
                     var newdate = new Date(date);
                     newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + 3);
                     var dd = newdate.getDate();
                     var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
                     var y = newdate.getFullYear();
                      var someFormattedDate = y + '/' + dd + '/' + mm;
                      $scope.expireDateOptions.maxDate = someFormattedDate;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your requirements, I have used the following to keep the minDate and maxDate set:

```
$scope.ChangeExpiryMinDate = function(availableDate) {
        if (availableDate != null) {
            var availableDate = new Date(availableDate);
            var expiryMinDate = angular.copy(availableDate);
            expiryMinDate.setDate(expiryMinDate.getDate() + 23);

            $scope.ExpireDate = availableDate;
            $scope.expireDateOptions.minDate = availableDate;
            $scope.expireDateOptions.maxDate = expiryMinDate;
        } else {
            delete $scope.ExpireDate;
        }
    };

$scope.ChangeExpiryMinDate($scope.AvailableDate);
```

You forgot to pass the current AvailableDate into the function, so when controller first loads, the Expiry Date Field is already limited.

To disable weekends, you can update the ExpiryDate Options with:

```
$scope.expireDateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yy',
    startingDay: 1,
    minDate: today,
    maxDate: "2017-06-12",
    dateDisabled: function(data) {
        var date = data.date;
        var mode = data.mode;
        return (mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 ));
    }
};
```

I have created a working JSFiddle here:  https://jsfiddle.net/1ahyk735/

Comment: The code you mentioned in fiddle is not working, i want to enable the Expire Date field once user selects date from Available Date field and Expire Date filed should only show 23 days followed by the date selected by the user in Available Date field.@user2340824

Comment: Thanks @user2340824, it worked.But the question i framed was wrong, i want to show 23 days by excluding saturday and sunday,

Comment: @participantjava sorry! I pasted the wrong Fiddle. I've updated the Fiddle as well as spotted another issue.

Comment: thankyou, i noticed it. Can we enable 23 days excluding saturday and sunday?